# Looping upload only uploads the first item

Tags: java, android, upload

I have a for loop running in the background, and it's uploading an array to my database online. However, it only uploads the first time it goes through, and I can't figure out why.

I can follow the code as it loops through the params.add and the upload, but when I look at my database, only one extra item is added each time. My success int is also set to 0 each time but the first one.

I've looked at similar problems, and tried to fix this, but I can't find anything. I'd appreciate any help on this.

This is the relevant code ( I call it with "new SavePotholeDetails().execute();" ):

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SensorActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading pothole details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Saving product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO: Get data from sensorData
        for (int i = 0; i < sensorData.size(); i++) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_TIME, Long.toString(sensorData.get(i).getTimestamp())));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ACCEL_X, Double.toString(sensorData.get(i).getX())));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ACCEL_Y, Double.toString(sensorData.get(i).getY())));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ACCEL_Z, Double.toString(sensorData.get(i).getZ())));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_CLIENT_ID, "Epidilius")); //TODO: Make a client ID variable
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_GPS_X, Double.toString(sensorData.get(i).getLat())));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_GPS_Y, Double.toString(sensorData.get(i).getLng())));

            // sending modified data through http request
            // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_update_pothole, "POST", params);

            // check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product updated
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

EDIT:

Here is the JSONParser class:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Comment: My guess: sensorData.size()==1

Comment: Pro tip: use foreach instead of that for. It should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just running a simple loop and not blocking the loop while your AsyncTasks are executing, then they're just getting fired all at once.  I also see that you're sending your web requests through the jsonParser object, but I don't know what that is.  If this object is shared between AsyncRequest instances (for example, if all of this stuff is scoped within a single Activity) or if the implementation blocks so that only one request can go out at a time, then everything after the first iteration of the loop is going to fail because your HTTP client is busy.

Without posting more than your AsyncTask code, I can't help much further than that.  You might want to think more about how you're executing your loop.  You could do something where the loop waits for each AsyncTask instance to call back (from the onPostExecute method) to signal that it's finished.  Or, you can do the looping inside of a single AsyncTask instance (probably a more lightweight solution as only a single thread is created).